# С полной версии сайта на мобильную и обратно (Redirect)

Tags: mobile, php

Друзья, наткнулся на следующее. Есть функция которая узнаёт пришёл ли к нам на основной сайт юзер с мобильного устройства. Если ДА то вовзращает TRUE если нет то FALSE

Всё ясно понятно, при каких состояниях и что делать. Но! Если мне нужно сделать ссылку на полную версию в МОБИЛЬНОЙ. Где нибудь в подвале сайта. То. Мне нужно сделать редирект туда же откуда я пришёл куда меня снова пошлёт обратно.

Был следующий вариант обработки. Клиент пришёл с мобильника? 
Да - старт сессия с именем mobile и значением - on.
Наш юзер переходит в мобильную версию, далее ему зачем то нужно было бы перейти к полной версии - клац по ссылке. Выполняется сценарий.

Значение mobile:on в сессии переписывается в mobile:off и кидает юзера в полную версию.
Как, друзья мои. Как сделать чёртову проверку на полной версии что бы это ЗАРАБОТАЛО наконец таки.

Comment: На вопрос пожалуйста. По делу ответьте